# Why traceroute sends UDP packets and not ICMP ones?

Tags: networking, udp, icmp, traceroute

According to the Stevens (TCP/IP Illustrated) the **traceroute** program sends UDP packets to the destination host with an incremental TTL (1, 2, 3, etc) to get the intermediate hops info from the **ICMP TTL EXPIRED** messages. 
The "*destination reached*" condition is an **ICMP PORT UNREACHABLE** message, because traceroute addresses a random port with an high number (that is: unlikely someone is listening there) 
So my question is: is there a technical reason (drawbacks, RFCs, etc.) to use UDP packets rather than using, for instance, **ICMP echo request** messages (with increasing TTL) and use the **echo reply** answer as the end condition? 
I understand that the ICMP echo reply might be filtered out by firewalls or other net devices in the middle, but I guess this can happen also to UDP packets ;)

Many Thanks 
Sergio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's actually the "old" method of doing traceroutes. I guess the main motivation was that sending out plain UDP packets requires no special privileges, as sending ICMP packets does (raw sockets or the equivalent). That's why e.g. `ping` is usually setuid to root, which is a big risk security-wise.

Nowadays `traceroute` supports ICMP and TCP probe packets as well, so you're more likely can sneak through firewalls, which are more likely than not deployed without consideration. This also means that `traceroute` is likely also setuid root on your system. See its man page, especially the part about available methods: http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute

Comment: UDP traceroute non-root